# How to have independent multiple radio buttons using bootsrap 5

Tags: html, radio-button, bootstrap-5

How do I make these two radio-button-groups independent?

If I select an answer in one row, it deselects the answer in the other row.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>

    <body class="p-3">
        <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
            <span class="input-group-text me-2 rounded" id="inputGroup-sizing-md">Test video</span>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">YouTube</label>
              
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Own video</label>
              
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio3">None</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mt-3" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
            <span class="input-group-text me-2 rounded" id="inputGroup-sizing-md">Test image</span>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio4" autocomplete="off" checked>
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio4">YouTube</label>
              
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio5" autocomplete="off">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio5">Own image</label>
              
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio6" autocomplete="off">
                <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio6">None</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In other words, I cannot choose `None` in the `Test video`-row and `YouTube` in the `Test image`-row at the same time.

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: change `name="btnradio"` in second row inputs to something else

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect, feel free to post as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `name="btnradio"` in second row inputs to something else